# Remote App Web Connection not working, possibly due to port forwarding

Tags: remoteapp

We have customers using our software via Remote App.

We have given them two options, using the .rdp file link we send them, or logging into the RDWeb and logging in that way.

We just recently discovered that the RDWeb has never worked (we only tested internally).

We are using an external port forwarding on a non-standard Remote Desktop port, to forward internally to the standard port of 3389 for the .rdp files.

My belief is that when using the Web Access, it is attempting to connect to the standard port rather than our port forwarded port, even though when I generated the .rdp file I specified the external port.

I believe this because I realize I never set a port to use for the RDWeb links.

Is there a way to configure what port the RDWeb links use?

We are using Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible out of the box without using a Remote Desktop Gateway as well. The RDWeb links will always go to port 3389 without RD Gateway.

See comments from Rand Morimoto on this blog post for some details:

http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/49566

If you implement a Remote Desktop Gateway, then external RDP traffic will come in over 443 to the Gateway server, and then use whatever RDP port you have specified internally. See this blog post for some setup details:

http://trycatch.be/blogs/roggenk/archive/2008/09/18/how-to-make-ts-web-access-remote-desktop-web-connection-work-over-ts-gateway.aspx

Comment: 2nd link is broken. This answer should never have been allowed to stay, it's really just a link only answer and is now basically worthless in its current form.